# Samba - Authenticating with Local User Accounts

Tags: linux, samba

I'm looking to have my users use their local accounts on my Linux servers without the need to create a separate user/password for Samba.  Is there any way to use the /etc/passwd file as the the authentication mechanism when they go to map a drive?  Can this be done using PAM?

I don't want to use AD as the domain ID's are different than those on the Linux servers.

Any advice/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If AD/Linux authentication is something you'd like later, you might check into Likewise Open

Answer (score 6):

samba cannot just use passwd/shadow, because several additional attributes are to be stored.

But you can setup samba with tdbsam-backend and let samba synchronise the passwords.

Or you setup an open ldap-backend for system and samba auth. But this is not that trivial ....

Comment: +1 - Sometimes, the answer is 'no' :)

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this resource: 
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Administration/Authentication-in-Samba/

it seems to cover exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It covers it, but not without some additional digging.

Comment: I suppose the extra work makes my answer unhelpful, considering the person who asked finished the question requesting a direction to be pointed in. meh.